# SymPy cannot solve the equation cos(x) = - 1 /cosh(x)

Tags: sympy

In Wolfram|Alpha, one can solve [cos λ = -1/cosh λ](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+%CE%BB+%3D+-1%2Fcosh+%CE%BB):

```
λ = ± 1.87510406871196...
λ = ± 4.69409113297417...
λ = ± 7.85475743823761...
λ = ± 10.9955407348755...
```

Why does cos(x) = - 1 /cosh(x) not work in SymPy?

I tried this:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True)  
eq = cos(x) + 1 /cosh(x)
ans=solve(eq)
print(ans)
# NotImplementedError: multiple generators [cos(x), exp(x)]
# No algorithms are implemented to solve equation cos(x) + 1/(exp(x)/2 + exp(-x)/2)
```

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

(2018/08/21)
Graphing Calculator

https://www.numberempire.com/graphingcalculator.php?functions=cos(x)%2C-1%2Fcosh(x)&xmin=0&xmax=10&ymin=-1.5&ymax=1.5&var=x

https://www.numberempire.com/graphingcalculator.php?functions=cos(x)*cosh(x)%2C-1&xmin=-10&xmax=10&ymin=-1.5&ymax=1.5&var=x

Comment: sympy is not simpy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sym" in SymPy stands for **symbolic**. Did WolframAlpha find a symbolic solution? No, it did not; because there isn't one. So, SymPy did not find one, either.

What you got from WolframAlpha is a **numeric** solution. To get those, there are other Python libraries, most notably [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html).

However, SymPy can get you numeric solutions too, by calling [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) under the hood. This is done with `nsolve`. It takes a second argument, initial point of the search for solution, and returns one solution.

```
>>> nsolve(eq, 0)
7.85475743823761
```

If you want more, try multiple starting points:

```
>>> {nsolve(eq, n) for n in range(-10, 10)}
{4.69409113297418, -1.87510406871196, 7.85475743823761, -7.85475743823761, 1.87510406871196, -10.9955407348755, -4.69409113297418}
```

Here I tried 20 starting points, some roots were repeated, hence the use of a set to eliminate the repetition.

There are infinitely many solutions; whatever tool is used, you'll only get several of those. But for large x, 1/cosh(x) is effectively 0, so the roots are approximately the same as cos(x) = 0, which are `pi/2 + pi*k`, any integer k.